# How to paginate in listview from one page to the other?

Tags: android, listview, pagination

I would like to know how to paginate in my listview from my first page to the second and so on and so forth. I have read abt using the Endless Adapter but that isn't a good idea since my data could go up to 1000. Preferably would be to press a 'Next' button and my listview would load the 2nd set of data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just clean your list and refill it with the next set of data on the button's click. Add a constraint for your list to have, for example, 20 or 30 items.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I know I have to do that. But is there any example code that I can follow?

Comment: Sorry, have no code to show you.. Just try to search through some ListView documentation, I believe it will be not that hard. Good luck!